# Cordova BarcodeScanner Plugin enable Aztec decoding

Tags: android, ios, cordova, zxing

We currently are using the Cordova BarcodeScanner plugin in our app to scan various barcodes and it works very well.  However in it's current state it is not able to scan Aztec barcodes and I need to be able to scan and decode Aztec barcodes.  It appears this plugin utilizes the zxing framework which I see does support Aztec barcodes.  I am looking for some direction or documentation that could walk me through on how to enable this to the existing plugin.

I have searched around quite a bit, but am very new to Cordova and Android and iOS development and feel like I am spinning my wheels.  If anyone has done this or has some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [cordova-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), in it's documentation has it supports Aztec for Android.

Comment: What about iOS? is aztec bar code scan available for Phonegap iOS anywhere?